# How to reduce log file size in Sybase Anywhere 11 during a Load statement

Tags: database-design, sqlanywhere

I've got a LOAD statement in a Sybase Anywhere 11 DB that I fire off. The problem is that it's an insert of about 500k records. In my transaction log, I see tons of inserts (in addition to my load) that look this: `SET n1 = n1 || [SOME LARGE HEX VALUES]`.

I know LOAD statements are just inserts, but is there anyway for me to just log a LOAD, instead of taking up > 100MB for one LOAD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue was not having this in the LOAD table statement: `WITH FILE NAME LOGGING`. According to the docs, it's the default. I believe it was because I was calling it from a client file. Regardless, it now shows only a LOAD table statement in the log file.